# Using Fuseki to federate different SPARQL endpoints

Tags: database, sparql, semantic-web, federated-queries

I work for a large organization with many different relational datastores containing overlapping information. We are looking for a solution for integrated querying on all our data at once. We are considering using Semantic Web technology for this purpose. Specifically, we plan to:

- Create a unified ontology
- Map each database to this ontology
- Create a SPARQL endpoint for each database
- Use a federation engine to unify them to one endpoint.

I am now in search of appropriate tools for the last stage of this plan. I have heard that Fuseki is appropriate for this case, but have been unable to find any relevant documentation.

Can you please give your opinion on the appropriateness of Fuseki for this task, or even better, point me at some proper documentation?

Thanks in advance!

Oren

Answer (score 1):

http://jena.apache.org/

You want to read about Fuseki but also able SPARQL basic federated query.  Fuseki itself is a query server, the query engine is ARQ.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest example of a federated query, that is supported by the ARQ engine (the backend to fuseki):
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/service.html

You submit this query to your fuseki endpoint, and it will go off and query the endpoint in the "service <>" brackets. This certainly works for me, using ARQ 2.9.4 with fuseki 0.2.6